# EditTexts inside ExpandableListView

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, expandablelistview

Hi I'm trying to make an activity that displays an ExpandableListView as shown in the figure.

When you click on the group it expands and shows a LinearLayout with a textview and an editext.

Right know the problem I have is that when a click on the EditText it doesn't get focus and I have to tap twice on it in order to make it get focus and display the keyboard, and then when I enter text I see nothing initially while I'm typing and then when I hide the Keyboard the EditText is updated with the text I typed

I've tried adding android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" to the expandableListVie layout, but the behaviour is the same.

Any Idea?? or any other way I could implement this layout??

[image: Expandable ListView with EditText]

Comment: Hey can u please help me. Can u please tell me the way how you can get that edittext values when this group item is collapsed.. I want to use this edit text values on on botom button event

Comment: jucas, did you find any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

add this to the manifest right after the android:name in your activity

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to fix the focusing problem, but I know why you have to collapse and expand the group to see the text in the editText. The listview doesn't refresh unless you scroll or you do something like expanding and collapsing the listview. So the best way I can think of to fix this problem is to create a list of strings that will be the values of the editTexts in the listview. Then create a onKeyClick() listener for each of the editTexts and do this:

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View editText, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        // Get the position of the item somehow
        int position = 4;
        // Get value from List<String> for editTexts
        String textValue = listOfValues.get(position);
        textValue = ((EditText)editText).getValue();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return false;
    }
});
```

What happens here is that you are getting the value of the editText once a key has been pressed, and are changing the value of the string in the list to the new value. Then you are telling the adapter that the value of one of the items has changed an it needs to refresh. Although this is not an efficient way to fix the problem, it is a backup solution in case you can't think of a better way.

Comment: but wait what exactly would you do with listOfValues

Comment: You wouldn't have to do anything with the listOfValues because the string 'textValue' is binded to the string in the listOfValues. So, when the value of textValue is changed, the value in listOfValues is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to store the values in the Edittext to a String variable using the function

```
String temp;

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        temp = s.toString();//editText.getText().toString();

        childValues[groupPosition][childPosition][]= temp ;

        Toast.makeText(context, ""+childValues[groupPosition][childPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and in the `getChild()` function always check for the data in temp and `settext()` value to that particular `edittext`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two things.

1) `expandableListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);`

2)In manifest(on your activity) `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`