# cannot type in edittext inside the expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-edittext

I am using an expandable ListView which contains 2 different children. The child layout contain 3 EditText fields. When I expand the group it displays the child layout, but I can't type any text to the edittext field.

My code in the custom expandable list adapter is given below:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean arg2, View childView,
        ViewGroup parent) 
{
    switch (groupPosition)
    {
    case 0:
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_personal_layout, null);
        final EditText fname = (EditText)childView.findViewById(R.id.editTextFname);
        fname.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fname.setFocusable(true);
            }
        });

        break;
    case 1:
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_experience_layout, null);
        break;
    case 2:
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_qualification_layout, null);
        break;
    case 3:
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_login_layout, null);
        break;
    case 4:
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_other_layout, null);
        break;
    }

    return childView;
}


public View getGroupView(int position, boolean arg1, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if(view==null)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_head, null);

    }
    TextView head = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view_head);
    head.setText(menu[position]);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1) May be your `editText` is not getting focus that's why you can't type anything. Try playing with the below line into the `xml-layout` file.

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

For more information about giving focus to the child element, you can refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability).

2) If the above solution is not working then you can try adding in listview.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    />
```

And Change the activity in mainfest.xml:

```
<activity android:name= ".yourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

3) If still not working, then have a look at this [link (focusable-edittext-inside-listview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview/2680077#2680077) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862081/edittexts-inside-expandablelistview/9947623#9947623).

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: where i want to add this line. with expandableListView or with child layout??

Comment: but when i use "blocksDescendants" i can't get the focus.. but instead of "blocksDescendants" i use "afterDescendants" but when i move to the next text box i lost what i typed on the ist text box

Comment: Add the above line into the outermost layout structure of the XML file (XML file where editText resides).

Comment: but when i use "blocksDescendants" i didnt get the focus

Comment: here i just use the android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
in the expandable list view now i can type int textbox but cant move the docus to the next focus

Comment: afterDescendants : "The ViewGroup will get focus only if none of its descendants want it". I think, That's why you have a focus first time but not after that.
You can refer this link for more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview

Comment: i am using expandable list view not listview. is there any problem when using expandable list view?? i am still stuck with this problem how can i solve can i contact you directly. my mail id is ranjithsankar.exe@gmail.com

Comment: @Vikky, I'm facing the same problem with ya. Could you tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746082/cannot-type-edittext-in-expandablelistview-child)
"adjustPan" is the key to store customer's input. The alternative way for focus:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/e_text_label"...>
    <requestFocus /> </TextView>
```