# onClick Childlist on ExpandableList Android

Tags: android, onclick, expandablelistview

i am using expandableList and each child has its edittext to enter a number... when the child is pressed, the edittext shows. if it is not, the edittext stays invisible..the problem is when i pressed child "A", some other childs (for example child "L" and "Z") also show the edittext... here is my code in main activity :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle konsumsi) {
        super.onCreate(konsumsi);
        setContentView(R.layout.konsumsi_user);
        exKonsumsi = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.EVkonsumsi_user);
        exKonsumsi.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        prepareListDataKonsumsi();
        exKonsumsiAdapter = new com.ta.helper.ExpandableListAdapterKonsumsi(
                this, listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser, listDataChildKonsumsiUser);
        exKonsumsi.setAdapter(exKonsumsiAdapter);
        kolomTakaran = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.takaran);
        takaran = ExpandableListAdapterKonsumsi.takaran;
        kolomTakaran.setText("" + takaran);
        exKonsumsi.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                EditText kolomEditTakaran = (EditText) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.kolomTakaran);
                CheckedTextView listChild = (CheckedTextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.lblListItemKonsumsi);
    /*          for (int i = 0; i < listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser.size(); i++) {
                    if (listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser.get(groupPosition) == listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser
                            .get(i)) {
                        int a = listDataChildKonsumsiUser.get(
                                listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser.get(i)).size();
                        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                            if (listChild.getText().toString() == listDataChildKonsumsiUser
                                    .get(listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser.get(i))
                                    .get(j)) {
                                kolomEditTakaran.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                            }else{
                                kolomEditTakaran.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }*/

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareListDataKonsumsi() {
        listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChildKonsumsiUser = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        Collections.addAll(listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser, getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.header_konsumsi_user));
        List<String> daftarMakananTersimpan = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> daftarMakanan = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(
                daftarMakanan,
                getResources().getStringArray(
                        R.array.child_konsumsi_user_daftar_makanan));
        Collections.addAll(
                daftarMakananTersimpan,
                getResources().getStringArray(
                        R.array.child_konsumsi_user_daftar_makanan_tersimpan));
        listDataChildKonsumsiUser.put(listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser.get(0),
                daftarMakananTersimpan);
        listDataChildKonsumsiUser.put(listDataHeaderKonsumsiUser.get(1),
                daftarMakanan);
    }
}
```

and I deleted my expandableadapter because i'm not using it anymore... i made a simple research by toasting the child and group position when i clicked... you know what... the child and group position randomly change everytime i scrolled up or down
hope somebody help :) thanks a lot..

Comment: Very similar to other recent postings, the problem is likely in the context AROUND your second block of code. Each row has a view that gets an OnClickListener, what's your plan for making sure that each row's OnClickListener has a way of finding out which row was clicked? A common pattern is to setTag() on something in each row, and have the OnClickListener call v.getTag() and use the result to decide which data item of your backing data corresponds to the cell that was cicked.

Comment: 'listChild' is your expandablelistview??

Comment: why dont u use 'setOnChildClickListener'..??

Comment: ASP... setOnChildClickListener is for the main activity and use main.xml ... the one i want to change is the EditText in childlistitem.xml...

Comment: @RobP i have tried what you suggested... but it didnt work..

Comment: the devil is in the details; you would have to post more or newer code to see why it didn't work. The setTag() trick is pretty standard for determining which row in an expandable list got a subview clicked, I've used it plenty.

Comment: @RobP i've edited it.. the code above is my current code..i dont know where is the devil

Comment: and what is the current behavior? have you set breakpoints to see if it hits each branch when you expect it to, and stepped through? By the way this code would be much cleaner and more concise if you used one or more arrays from resources, all these hard-coded strings and lengthy if...else  constructs make the code difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: @RobP .. hehe...oke i'll do it later... back to the problem, when i click child "1", the edittext appears...but it appears also in child "5" and "9" (randomly).. if i slide till the very end and slide up again, sometimes the edittext in child "1" disappears...

Comment: @RobP i've changed my code and try everything but it remains awful...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my answer is stupid: a quick look on your program shows that you use `==` and `!=` for Java String. This is not supposed to work with Java 6, as far as I know. Java 7 ?

Consider using `string1.equals(string2)` instead, this may help.

Comment: it doesnt really solve my problem..but thank you for having time to help :D