# ExpandableListView with EditText in child for Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView that has an EditText in each of its child items. After I enter some text in the EditText and then expand/collapse in ExpandableListView, what I entered in the EditText disappears.

I have read similar questions but I have not found the correct answer. For example, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746082/cannot-type-edittext-in-expandablelistview-child).

How can I preserve the values of the EditText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you expand a ExpandableListView, the getChildView( ) is triggered. So what ever code you have written in this call back, will be executed to reDraw the child as if it never existed. Now it is upto your logic, how do you handle this:

1. SavedInstanceState
2. SetTag() & GetTag()
3. A parallel list that holds what each of the edittext holds

Then you can add this logic to the getChildView() call back.