# EditText in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I added `EditText` in `ExpandableListView` in the group item, after that when I'm clicking on the group item, list with children items doesn't appear. What can be the problem? Is it possible this list to be expanded in that case? Or it's forbidden to add `EditText` in group item in `ExpandedListView`?

Code of the adapter:

```
public class ClaimEqpExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    public List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ClaimEqpExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                         HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    public ClaimEqpExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_explist_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_eq_list_group, null);
           // convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list_group, null);
        }

        TextView tvWorkNumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvWorkNumber);
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvClaimWorkName);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        int displayPosition=groupPosition+1;
        tvWorkNumber.setText(String.valueOf(displayPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    public void updateData(List<String> groups,
                           HashMap<String, List<String>> children) {
        this._listDataHeader = groups;
        this._listDataChild = children;
    }
}
```

claim_eq_list_group.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWorkNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvClaimWorkName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvWorkNumber"
        android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/tvClaimEquip"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvClaimWorkName"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

claim_explist_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dip" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post the code...

Comment: @Lino just have added

Comment: Try this: yourEditText.setFocusable(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found three solution for this problem:

1) make `EditText` unfocusable first, and then make it focusable while typing text.

Code in the adapter:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        return false;
    }
});
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        editText.setFocusable(false);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    }
```

2) Make custom `Expandable indicator` (Button), set on it `onClickListener`, which will expand and collapse `ExpandableListView`.

Code in the adapter:

```
btnIndicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) mParetn;
                if(mExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(mGroupPosition)){
                    mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(mGroupPosition);
                }else{
                    mExpandableListView.expandGroup(mGroupPosition);
                }
            }
        });
```

3) Instead of `EditText`, make a `TextView` or `Button`. on pressing of which appears Alert Dialog with EditText, where user can insert input.

Answer (score 0):

The editText inside the groupheader is focusable and is stealing all the click events. Try to set focusable to false:
`android:focusable="false"` or `yourEditText.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: Now I can see child list, but can't type anything in this EditText field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746082/cannot-type-edittext-in-expandablelistview-child

Comment: Tried it, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

set below properties in your xml Edittext.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

if Still not work then add in you listview

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants
```

And in manifest in that activity add.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Tried, still can't type anything in EditText